# Queue commands to last subshel even if one of them launches new shell

Tags: shell, automation, shell-script, solaris, ksh

I want to automate something writing simple script launching consecutively few scripts one after another. And then setting some aliases at the top shell.
Problem: few of these commands launch new shell. And all commands after that one are launched in previous shell. Is there anyway to queue these commands coming after that one in "top" shell?
Simple Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#normally this ksh is executed deep inside other script i cannot modify
ksh
echo test
```

Is there any way to print "test" on shell just started by ksh command?
Normally test is printed in previous shell - becomes available after "exit" command
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your use of "top shell" is slightly confusing. You mean the last subshell that you started, right?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four alternatives, but each of them has a drawback:

1. Make sure that the commands that you want to execute in the ksh are written to the file `mycmds` and start the ksh in the following form:

   ```
   cat mycmds /dev/tty | ksh -i
   ```

   *Drawback:* You lose the command-line editing features of ksh.
2. Make sure that the commands that you want to execute in the ksh are written to the file `/tmp/mycmds$$`; set the environment variable `MYCMDS` to `/tmp/mycmds$$` before starting `ksh -l`; and add the following to your `$HOME/.profile`:

   ```
   if [ -n "$MYCMDS" ] ; then
       . "$MYCMDS"
       MYCMDS=
       export MYCMDS
   fi
   ```

   *Drawback:* Everybody who uses this program has to modify his `$HOME/.profile`.
3. Organize the entire thing in such a way that the commands you want to execute are written to a file `mycmds` which is then sourced via `. mycmds` in the *initial* shell. Put all that into a function definition.

   *Drawback*: Rather than starting a new shell, you modify the environment and/or alias definitions of the initial one. Everybody who uses this program has to use ksh.
4. Make sure that the commands that you want to execute are written to the file `mycmds` and start a *bash* in the following form:

   ```
   bash -i --init-file mycmds
   ```

   *Drawback:* You get a bash instead of a ksh.

Comment: lshmm, the result is almost what i want when i use : ( cat mycmds /dev/tty ) | ksh   (without the -i ). But the prefix before.. dont know how this is called before -> "you can type here" no longer appears

Comment: It's called "prompt". Without `-i` or `-l`, a ksh that reads from a pipeline is not an interactive one (`man ksh`), which means in particular that there is no prompt.

Comment: By the way, the parentheses around `cat mycmds /dev/tty` are useless. Originally, I had two commands here; after deleting one of them I should also have deleted the parentheses.

Comment: Hmm, ok. However when i use the -i. that shell window is "stuck" it does not accept commands anymore. or should i say it doesnt responds anymore. And without the -i option ( no longer interactive ) my .profile aliases arent visible in this new shell.

Comment: You're right about the problems with `-i`, and the version without this option doesn't work well either. I'd go for method 2 or 4 (2 is essentially an emulation of the bash `--init-file` option.)

Comment: Ok, so I worked this out! Within my script, at the end of it I split current terminal (e.g xterm &). And I Launch it using cat myScript | ksh. Everything works great now! thanks. The new terminal that opens has everything set, and the old one is disposable.